# What's the behaviour of rendering a line on the exact coordinates of a triangle's vertices

Tags: opengl

I want to render a line overlay `glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 6)` between 2 vertices of a triangle. If I generate that triangle on the geometry shader, does OpenGL guarantee that GL_LEQUAL depth test will work?Also, if I set glLineWidth to something different than 1, like 10, what's the behaviour? Does opengl render the whole line as if depth testing was disabled, or does it render something like a semicylinder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL's invariance rules don't apply if you're rendering two different kinds of primitives (lines vs. triangles). The presence or absence of a geometry shader is therefore irrelevant.

The depth of the wide fragments of a line is a function of line rasterization. Basically a wide-line is conceptually multiple renderings of the same line beside each other. As such, all pixels in the "wide" segment of a line will get the same depth values. So the columns or rows of a wide line will all have the same depth value.

Comment: Can you guide me with a link to these invariance rules?